# How do I convert a string of numbers to 24 time

Tags: c#, datetime

How do I convert a string of numbers to 24 time

string example would be something like "0800" or "1200" or "2400"

I'd like this to be parsed to time data type (but without date) so that I can compare 2 times against each other. I parsed them as int numbers, but then it trimmed left zero's on numbers like "0800"

Comment: Do you want a DateTime (eg. always includes date, so "at 9 PM *today*") or an Interval/TimeSpan (eg. time since an event, "daily at half past noon")?

Comment: not sure what interval is actually, I've never used it. I think I'd play it safe and go with DateTime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var ts  = TimeSpan.ParseExact("1500", "hhmm",null);
```

You can compare them, for ex

```
var ts1 = TimeSpan.ParseExact("1500", "hhmm", null);
var ts2 = TimeSpan.ParseExact("2000", "hhmm", null);
var mins = ts2.Subtract(ts1).TotalMinutes;
```

Comment: as the question asked for 24-hours time format, you'll need the `"HHmm"` format string

Comment: @andreask No it is correct, you may want to read docs about TimeSpan.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @B.K. HHmm is valid for DateTime, but TimeSpan uses hhmm

Comment: @B.K. I wrote it under wrong answer, it was meant for your other (deleted now)comment...

Comment: sorry, you're correct, mixed it up with the `DateTime` specification. Strange that both are using different format strings, though....

Comment: Something that's throwing off my program is when I get a time of 800 instead of 0800. the parser can't handle it. Do you know how I could get around this?

Comment: @Frantumn maybe `"800".PadLeft(4,'0')`? this would work for 4char string also

Comment: @EZI Oh, I love that last comment solution! Padding... much better than what I thought of.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the result as `DateTime` object, take a look at the `DateTime.ParseExact` method:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't want the date portion, `TimeSpan` is your best bet.

**CODE:**

```
var time1 = "0800";
var time2 = "1200";
var time3 = "2359"; // 2400 is not a valid time


var ts1 = TimeSpan.ParseExact(time1, "hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var ts2 = TimeSpan.ParseExact(time2, "hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var ts3 = TimeSpan.ParseExact(time3, "hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(ts1);
Console.WriteLine(ts2);
Console.WriteLine(ts3);

// Calculating time difference.
var tsDiff = ts1.Subtract(ts2);

Console.WriteLine(tsDiff);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
08:00:00
12:00:00
23:59:00
-04:00:00
```

Comment: Something that's throwing off my program is when I get a time of 800 instead of 0800. the parser can't handle it. Do you know how I could get around this?

Comment: @Frantumn There are a couple of ways.  One way is to do something like this: `while (timeString.Length < 4) { timeString = "0" + timeString; }`  That will get it up to four characters.

Comment: @Frantumn I like EZI's solution to the missing `0` issue better.  Check his comments under his solution.